# How with larastan fix errors in Resource file?

Tags: laravel

On laravel site Running larastan on LanguageResource.php file with lines :

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class LanguageResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'     => $this->id,
            'locale' => $this->locale,
            'prefix' => $this->prefix,
        ];
    }

}
```

I got next errors :

```
  19     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LanguageResource::$id.
      Learn more: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-access-to-undefined-property
  20     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LanguageResource::$locale.
      Learn more: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-access-to-undefined-property
  21     Access to an undefined property App\Http\Resources\LanguageResource::$prefix.
     Learn more: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-access-to-undefined-property
```

Usually when dealing similar errors with mopels I use getAttribute method, but it does not work in this case, as $this is an Resource object here.
Can I got model in this resource or to salve in it some other case ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.8",
"nunomaduro/larastan": "^2.0",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add /** @mixin Language */ before class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying JSON Resource classes as "[Universal Object Crates](https://phpstan.org/config-reference#universal-object-crates)", by adding this to your phpstan.neon file:

```neon
parameters:
    universalObjectCratesClasses:
        - Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may end up here in the future, here is the approach I recommend. As @georgebuilds said above, the [Universal Object Crates](https://phpstan.org/config-reference#universal-object-crates) provides an easy way for PHPStan to ignore what's going on; however, from the PHPStan docs:

> Classes without predefined structure are common in PHP applications. They are used as universal holders of data - any property can be set and read on them.

The issue here is that a `JsonResource` *does* often have defined data on them.

For my example here, I will assume that `LanguageResource` relies on an underlying `Language` model, and `LanguageResource` will **only** be used for the `Language` model:

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\Language;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

/**
 * @mixin Language
 */
class LanguageResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function __construct(Language $resource)
    {
        parent::__construct($resource);
    }

    public function toArray(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'id'     => $this->id,
            'locale' => $this->locale,
            'prefix' => $this->prefix,
        ];
    }

}
```

The two keys items are:

1. The `@mixin` docblock informs PHPStan (and potentially your IDE as well) that everything contained within `Language` should be available here. If you have properly documented your model's parameters, PHPStan will look there and find them.
2. The `__construct()` ensures this `JsonResource` is only called by the correct model.

I personally keep my code at PHPStan Level 9, and I can confirm this approach works there.